# Trying to change purchase-button text if has term category + is variable WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

Everything works good if I remove the `&& $product->is_type( 'variable' )`

However, when I add that line, the first if, doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Expecting: If product is in category "farsk-ved" and is a variable product, the text should be "Välj längd". So all the single products, should go to the "else" section ("Köp").

What is happening: All products, except the "elseif" part, is getting "köp".

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_loop_add_to_cart_button', 20, 2 ); 
function custom_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button_text ) {
    // BELOW set the product categoty slug and the product ID
$product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() );

    if ( has_term( 'farsk-ved', 'product_cat') && $product->is_type( 'variable' )) {

        $button_text = __("Välj längd", "woocommerce");
    }
    elseif ( has_term( 'torr-ved', 'product_cat') ) {

        $button_text = __("Välj mängd", "woocommerce");
    }
    else {
        $button_text = __("Köp", "woocommerce");
    }
    return $button_text;
}
```

Comment: Did you check with this `$product->get_type()=='variable'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The real way:** the `WC_Product` Object is directly included for [`woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#1805-1812) filter hook as 2nd argument *(and **missing** from your function code)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_loop_add_to_cart_button', 20, 2 ); 
function custom_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button_text, $product ) { // <== the missing argument 
    // BELOW set the product category Id, slug or name
    if ( has_term( 'farsk-ved', 'product_cat') && $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        $button_text = __("Välj längd", "woocommerce");
    }
    elseif ( has_term( 'torr-ved', 'product_cat') ) {
        $button_text = __("Välj mängd", "woocommerce");
    }
    else {
        $button_text = __("Köp", "woocommerce");
    }
    return $button_text;
}
```

Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `$product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() );` and `$product->is_type( 'variable' )` it will return **bool(false)**

If you use `$product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() );` and `$product->get_type()` it will return **simple** for all products including variable type.

So you just need to use like this,

```
$product = new WC_Product_Variable($product_id);
if ( has_term( 'farsk-ved', 'product_cat') && $product->get_type()=='variable') {
```

I think this will help.

Comment: That didn't help either, even if it's a single product it's still showing the value of that rows IF (Välj längd)

Comment: I had to use global $product;

Comment: @ErikaJohansson did you changed this `$product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() );` to `$product = new WC_Product_Variable($product_id);`

Comment: Yes I did, it might matter that I am outside the loop though?

Comment: which loop, I cant find any loops in your question?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to replace `$product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() );`
 with `global $product;`

Comment: I am still getting `bool(false)` as you mentioned in the answer.